# Array reorders and replaces help. (keys and values to a new array)

Tags: php, nested, key, jquery-ui-sortable

Please help me in this case. I've got an array, and I'd like to make a new one, like

```
array[0][id] = 1
array[0][parent_id] = null
array[0][order_id] = 1
array[1][id] = 2
array[1][parent_id] = null
array[1][order_id] = 2
etc.
```

My current array is like this:

```
Array
(
[list] => Array // if the (array's name = `list`) the array[#][parent_id] = null
    (
        [0] => 1 // the key of the array (`[0]` in this case) is the array[#][order_id]
        [1] => 2 // the value of the array (`2` in this case) is the array[#][id]
        [2] => 5
    )

[list_2] => Array // else the array[#][parent_id] = the number value after the _
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 4
    )

[list_5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
    )
)
```

**A good solution based on Habax's script:**

```
$new = array();
$n=0;
foreach($old as $key=>$item){
    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($item); $i++) {
        if($key=='list')$new[$n]['parent_id']=null;
        else {
          $tmp = explode('_', $key);
          $new[$n]['parent_id']=$tmp[1];
        }
        $new[$n]['order_id']=$i;
        $new[$n]['id']=$item[$i-1];
        $n++;
    }
}
}
```

**Good to arrange nested sortables, like: http://www.b-hind.eu/jquery/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sur to understand your line

```
[0] => 1 // the key of the array (`[0]` in this case) is the array[#][order_id]
```

I will suppose it's the value, not the key:

```
$new = array();
$n=0;
foreach($old as $key=>$item){
  if($key=='list')$new[$n]['parent_id']=null;
  else {
    $tmp = explode('_', $key);
    $new[$n]['parent_id']=$tmp[1];
  }
  $new[$n]['order_id']=$item[0];
  $new[$n]['id']=$item[1];
  $n++;
}
```

Comment: i mean in that case the array[#][order_id] = 0, yes :P

Comment: Is there a case where order_id is not 0 ?

Comment: Yes. in the list_N: [order_id] => id, like: [0] => 3, [1] => 4. And i need all the elements in the array, i made some chaging in your script, and its almost good. :P